# Applying Header text (title) to a ScrolledComposite having a GridLayout

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am having a  `ScrollledComposite` with Layout set as `GridLayout` and data set as `GridData`. This I am using on a `Graphical editor`

I need to add a heading to the composite which I wish to be static in place and not get scrolled up as the content of the scrolled composite is scrolled up.

I tried adding a label in the scrolled composite but as the contents of the grid is populated the label is hidden, which I suppose is due to the grid view taking the space occupied by thw label.

Comment: `ScrolledComposite` does not support this.

Comment: Does ScrolledComposite can contain only single direct Child (which in turn can contain multiple children) or it can contain multiple direct children.

Comment: Well it extends `Composite` so in theory you can add multiple direct children, but the `ScrolledComposite` layout appears to force the main `setContent` control to occupy the whole area of the control.

Comment: hmm I guessed that as I worked in Android earlier and there too a ScrollLayout can only have a single direct child. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `Group`   as a parent Composite to my `ScrolledComposite`. The java class `Group extends Composite` and also has an option to setting the Text. I applied the font data to the text and I was able to add the header.